# Are there any Review audits?

Tags: support, review

Are there any Review audits like on Stack Overflow? I already did some reviews but never had an audit in *First Posts* or *Late Answers*, so I wanted to ask if here are also review audits in the different queues?

If there are no review audits here, why is this the case? The audits on Stack Overflow really helped me to learn what are good and bad questions for this site.

Comment: I *doubt* there are review audits. Unless RNG is playing tricks with me.

Comment: I have never seen one, so I would guess no. They take a lot of management to do good, so I don't think many of the smaller sites have them. If you have question about reviewing and want some advice, feel free to ask here or in chat.

Comment: In addition to what Anders said, if you have a question about a _specific_ review, you can also ask on Meta. Just glancing through your existing contributions, you seem to have a good idea of the level of quality expected on Stack Exchange. I think you'll do fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some sites have Review audits. Information Security is not one of them.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/384528) on the main Meta site which lists the sites which do have them.

Comment: Thanks for the meta answer. Didn't See that before.